# KnockoutJS bindings not showing

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS with the mapping plugin to map a MVC viewmodel to a viewmodel property;

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.EntityKey = 0;
    self.observables = ko.observable();
    self.RoleName = ko.observable("");

    // CRUD Actions
    self.getPaged = function (page) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Core/Authentication/Role/UpdateIndex",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { pageNumber: page },
            success: function (result) {
                self.observables = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            },
        });
    };

    this.remove = function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Core/Authentication/Role/Delete",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { userId: data.EntityKey() },
            success: function (result) {
                self.getPaged(self.observables.CurrentPage);
                toastr.success(result);
            },
        });
    };

    this.update = function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Core/Authentication/Role/Update",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            success: function (result) {
                toastr.success(result);
            },
        });
    };

    this.create = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Core/Authentication/Role/Create",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            success: function (result) {
                self.getPaged(self.observables.CurrentPage);
                toastr.success(result);
                self.RoleName("");
            },
        });
    };

    self.getPaged(1);                      
}

$(function () {
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

And this is my view;

```
<table data-bind="visible: observables.PageItems">
    <tr>
        <th>@AuthRes.Resource.EntityKey</th>
        <th>@AuthRes.Resource.RoleName</th>
        <th>@AuthRes.Resource.Update</th>
        <th>@AuthRes.Resource.Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: observables.PageItems">
        <td><span data-bind="text: $data.EntityKey" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.RoleName" /></td>
        <td><a data-bind="click: $root.update.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Update</a></td>
        <td><a href='#' data-bind="click: $root.remove.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>@AuthRes.Resource.CreateNew</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@AuthRes.Resource.RoleName</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" required="required" data-bind="value: RoleName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.create" />@AuthRes.Resource.Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

viewModel.observables is updating correctly, and the data is correct, but for some reason isn't binding to the foreach for observables.PageItems.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The `foreach` will apply to the childs of your tag.**

With your code

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: observables.PageItems">
    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.EntityKey" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.RoleName" /></td>
    <td>
      <a data-bind="click: $root.update.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Update</a>
    </td>
    <td>
     <a href='#' 
        data-bind="click: $root.remove.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Delete</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

**Only one `tr` will be created.**

Try with the containerless syntax:

```
<!-- ko foreach: observables.PageItems -->
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.EntityKey" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.RoleName" /></td>
    <td>
      <a data-bind="click: $root.update.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Update</a>
    </td>
    <td>
     <a href='#' 
        data-bind="click: $root.remove.bind($data)">@AuthRes.Resource.Delete</a>
     </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**2.Also, for your check for the `visible` binding you might want to try**

```
<table data-bind="visible: observables.PageItems().length > 0">
```

**3.Your mapping syntax is not correct**

When you declare `self.observables = ko.observable();` and you bind to it, knockout will create a link so that when you update `self.observables` the html will update.

Now when you do this `self.observables = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);`, it does not update, it breaks the link and assign a new observable. That means the html will no more be updated.

This syntax `self.observables = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);` is correct if you do it before binding (`ko.applyBindings`), but you don't have the data just yet.

What you can do is use an `if` binding to check if your data has been loaded. This will prevent binding links to be created when the `if` condition is not met (bindings will be recreated every time your condition changes to true). This way your binding will not break.

```
<!-- ko if: hasInit -->
<table data-bind="visible: observables.PageItems">
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
<!-- /ko --->
```

And the js

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.EntityKey = 0;
    self.hasInit = ko.observable(false);
    //self.observables = ko.observable(); //REMOVE THIS LINE, 
                                          //observables will be created after
    self.RoleName = ko.observable("");

    // CRUD Actions
    self.getPaged = function (page) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Core/Authentication/Role/UpdateIndex",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { pageNumber: page },
            success: function (result) {
                if (typeof self.observables === 'undefined') { //first call
                    self.observables = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
                     self.hasInit(true);
               } else //updates
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(results, self.observables);
            },
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Whilst that will help, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. The whole table is remaining hidden despite PageItems containing data.

Comment: I've made the change but the table still isn't showing. The data is definitely updating though, I have an alert in there, currently there are 15 records.

Comment: If I change the mapping syntax (3) and use the following;
alert(ko.toJSON(self.observables.PageItems));
I get undefined, whereas the first way it gives me the items

Comment: Indeed it is more complicated than that, I will update

Comment: I've made the latest updates, but I now receive this error;

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return observables.PageItems }"
Message: observables is not defined

Comment: You should not enter this, do you have the if binding set at the right place? I forgot to update hasInit to, will correct

Comment: I've added the change to HasInit, but this error still appears on page first load and no data is showing

Comment: !!!!

Sorry, I put the Init on the wrong html page!

I've done this and it works now, you are my hero!